# Prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\bigg(1+\frac{\alpha}{f(n)}\bigg)^{f(n)}=e^\alpha$

Tags: limits, constants

how to prove that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\bigg(1+\frac{\alpha}{f(n)}\bigg)^{f(n)}=e^\alpha$$

where $f(n)$ is any function, such  $$\lim_{n \to \infty}f(n)=\infty$$

Comment: If you are ok, you can accept the answer and set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's immediate from:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\bigg(1+\frac{\alpha}{f(n)}\bigg)^{f(n)}=\lim_{f(n) \to \infty}\bigg(1+\frac{\alpha}{f(n)}\bigg)^{f(n)}=e^\alpha$$

As an alternative by taylor expansion:

$$\bigg(1+\frac{\alpha}{f(n)}\bigg)^{f(n)}=e^\alpha=e^{f(n)\log \bigg(1+\frac{\alpha}{f(n)}\bigg)}=e^{f(n)\bigg(\frac{\alpha}{f(n)}+o\left(\frac{1}{f(n)}\right)\bigg)}=e^{\alpha+o(1)}\to e^\alpha$$

Answer (score 2):

If 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}f(n)=\infty$$
then it follows immediately that 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\bigg(1+\frac{\alpha}{f(n)}\bigg)^{f(n)}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\bigg(1+\frac{\alpha}{n}\bigg)^{n}=e^\alpha.$$
You should probably think about why that is...

Comment: Maybe you would like to clarify, why $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\bigg(1+\frac{\alpha}{n}\bigg)^{n}=e^\alpha$.

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. Seems part of the standard literature to me.

Comment: The odd appearance in this question is definitely the limit.

Comment: $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\bigg(1+\frac{\alpha}{n}\bigg)^{n}=e^\alpha$ posibly the most difficult here, it's hard to say is it standard or not...

Comment: The definition of $e$ is $e:=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\bigg(1+\frac{1}{n}\bigg)^{n}$

Answer (score 1):

Note that 
$$
  \lim_{n \to \infty}\bigg(1+\frac{\alpha}{f(n)}\bigg)^{f(n)}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \bigg(1+\frac{1}{\frac{f(n)}{\alpha}}\bigg)^{\frac{f(n)}{\alpha}} \right)^{\alpha}.
$$
So, if $n \to \infty$ then $\frac{f(n)}{\alpha} \to \infty$ and the inner part goes to $e$.